# Combine my results into a single flat table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Suppose I have an sql statement

```
select a.Date, count(a.Id) as Apples from dbo.apples as a group by a.Date
```

which yields a result

```
Date      Apples
10/1/2011 4
10/2/2011 6
10/4/2011 8
```

And I have a second query

```
select o.Date, count(o.Id) as Oranges from dbo.Oranges as o group by o.Date
```

which yields the result

```
Date      Oranges
10/2/2011 3
10/3/2011 5
10/4/2011 7
```

I would like to combine the two results into a single result like

```
Date      Apples Oranges
10/1/2011 4      0
10/2/2011 6      3
10/3/2011 0      5
10/4/2011 8      7
```

I tried

```
select select a.Date, count(a.Id) as Apples from dbo.apples as a group by a.Date
union 
select o.Date, count(o.Id) as Oranges from dbo.Oranges as o group by o.Date
```

which didn't give me the expected results, what I got was more like

```
Date      Apples
10/1/2011 4   
10/2/2011 6
10/2/2011 3
10/3/2011 5
10/4/2011 8
10/4/2011 7
```

with no mention of Oranges.

What should the final sql statement look like (I prefer performant and concise over not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date,sum(apples) as apples,sum(oranges) as Oranges
from
(
select a.Date as theDate, count(a.Id) as Apples,0 as Oranges 
from dbo.apples as a group by a.Date 
union all
select o.Date, 0 as apples, count(o.Id) as Oranges
 from dbo.Oranges as o 
 group by o.Date 
) xx
group by theDate
```

Comment: Exactly what i was going to suggest. +1.  Faster typer than me.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It would already be marked as the answer... where I not required to wait for 5 more minutes... =p

Comment: Question, in this case, what is difference between `union` and `union all`

Comment: Union will do distinct records and we know we have deliberate duplicates on the date.  Union all picks them all up.

Comment: As Mike said, union adds an extra step to remove duplicates.   Union all eliminates the need for this step, helps performance if  you don't have duplicates to remove